# I'm logged in, and I forgot my password for my account with a encrypted home

Tags: 16.04, encryption, password-recovery

Is there anyway to fix this? I only don't know 3 letters (I think), and I want to know if there's a way to fix this, like using John The Ripper or something. The problem is that if I were to reboot, my files are basically toast. As a result I need help FAST. My version is Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1.

Comment: Of course, you could back up the decrypted files then create a new user and move the files to the new home directory, but that might be prohibitive if you don't have a suitable backup medium.

Comment: Seen this Q before, can't search now though. One answer lies in `keyctrl`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to crack your password. But that is by no means certain. The only advice I can give you is to back-up your files fast (see the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Synchronization_and_backup_programs) for a list of examples).

E.g.

```
rsync -avz /home/_username_ /media/_a_large_external_hard_drive_
```